# Non vanishing of group cohomology

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a finite group, then $H^n(G,\mathbb{Z})\neq 0$ for infinitely many $n$. This is not hard to see for cyclic groups. Can we prove this fact algebraically, could anyone provide a reference? Thanks

Comment: You mean nontrivial finite group, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This link may prove useful:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/64688/non-vanishing-of-group-cohomology-in-sufficiently-high-degree

As mentioned on the above page, Swan proved the result in:

R. G. Swan, *The nontriviality of the restriction map in the cohomology of groups*, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 11 (1960), 885-887.

Comment: This argument, slightly fleshed out, is also in volume 2 of Benson's *Representations and Cohomology*.